# Disable selected date in calendar retrative date from database

Tags: database, vb.net, date, calendar

I want to do a Calendar using VB.net which have dates highlighted/disable when the column `Date` 02/06/2015 repeat three times then disable same date in calendar, if less than three no change in calendar date, all these dates are retrieved from a database.

```
_______________________________________________
ID  |     Name     |   IDNo    |     Date     |
-----------------------------------------------
 1  |     A        |  1235     |  02/06/2015  |
 3  |     B        |  1236     |  02/06/2015  |
 4  |     C        |  1237     |  02/06/2015  |
 5  |     D        |  1238     |  03/06/2015  |
 6  |     E        |  1239     |  03/06/2015  |
 7  |     F        |  1240     |  05/06/2015  |
 8  |     G        |  1241     |  05/06/2015  |
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask].

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

this code disable only first date in calendar,,,,

```css
Dim sql As String = "Select (Date) From PersonalData Group By date having date>=2"
    Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
        If (reader.Read()) Then
            If (reader.HasRows) Then
            While reader.Read()
                Calendar1.SelectedDates.Add(CType(reader.GetDateTime(0), Date))
                Calendar1.SelectedDayStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
                nextdate = Calendar1.SelectedDate
                If nextdate = e.Day.Date Then
                    e.Cell.Text = "--"
                End If
            End While
            End If
        End If
```